# Asp.Net MVC DropDownList issue

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, html.dropdownlistfor

I am trying to display dropdown in my asp.net mvc application.I got strucked on setting the list items in Priorities. What would be my mistake here?

```
public IList<SelectListItem> Priorities { get; set; }
Priorities = new List<SelectListItem>();
Priorities.Add(new IList<SelectListItem>
                {
                    new SelectListItem { Text = "High", Value = "1"},
                    new SelectListItem { Text = "Low", Value = "0"}
                });

@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectedPriority, Model.Priorities, "Select one")
```

Comment: Change `Priorities.Add(new IList<SelectListItem> {..` to `Priorities.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "High", Value="1" });`

Comment: I am trying to add multiple items at a time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing

```
Priorities = new List<SelectListItem>();
```

By

```
Priorities = new List<SelectListItem>() {
                new SelectListItem { Text = "High", Value = "1"},
                new SelectListItem { Text = "Low", Value = "0"}
            };
```

Or Cast and AddRange

```
 ((List<SelectListItem>)Priorities).AddRange(
                new List<SelectListItem>() {
                    new SelectListItem { Text = "High", Value = "1"},
                    new SelectListItem { Text = "Low", Value = "0"}
                }

            );
```

Other option using IEnumerable :

```
public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Priorities { get; set; }
Priorities = new List<SelectListItem>();

Priorities = Priorities.Concat(new List<SelectListItem>() {
                new SelectListItem { Text = "High", Value = "1"},
                new SelectListItem { Text = "Low", Value = "0"}
                }
        );
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't instantiate an interface here:

```
Priorities.Add(new IList<SelectListItem>
{
    new SelectListItem { Text = "High", Value = "1"},
    new SelectListItem { Text = "Low", Value = "0"}
});
```

Instead try to instantiate it as something that implements IList and use AddRangewhich is meant for this kind of situation:

```
Priorities.AddRange(new List<SelectListItem>
{
  new SelectListItem { Text = "High", Value = "1"},
  new SelectListItem { Text = "Low", Value = "0"}
});
```